# Bijections of a finite field that preserve the kernel of the trace

Tags: finite-fields, trace, trace-map

Let $q=p^n$, for some prime $p$ and positive integer $n$. Let $m$ also be a positive integer, and denote $Tr$ to be the [trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_trace) of $GF(q^m)$ over $GF(q)$.

I have the suspicion that all the functions $f(x): GF(q^m)\rightarrow GF(q^m)$ which preserve the Kernel of the trace, i.e.

$$
Tr(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow Tr(f(x))=0, \;\text{ for all } x\in GF(q^m),
$$

are of the form $f(x)=cx^{p^r}$ for $c\in GF(q)$, $c\neq 0$, and $0\leq r < mn$.

It is not hard to show that functions of the above form do preserve the trace, however I was not able to show the other direction.

Is my suspicion true? If yes, how can we show that *every* functions that preserves the trace is of the form given above?

Comment: What do you mean by *automorphism* of a finite field? Obviously not a field automorphism, but what? Additive bijection? Linear bijection? The numbers in my answer will move closer to each other, but won't match.

Comment: I think I was being quite careless when I wrote that title. It should be just bijections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how this could be true. There are just too many functions preserving the kernel of the trace.

For example consider the case $q=2$, $m=5$. The kernel of the trace has $16$ elements, and $16$ other elements in $GF(32)$. The function $f$ can permute both sets of $16$ any which way you want. This gives us $(16!)^2$ bijective functions that preserve the kernel. OTOH there are only ten functions of the form $cx^{2^r}$, $c\in GF(2), 0\le r<5$.

Observe also that all those functions can be realized as polynomials by applying Lagrange's interpolation formula.

---

This was too easy, so I suspect that you have left out a key assumption.

---

Guessing that you want the function $f$ to be a bijection that is linear over $GF(q)$.
Let's do the same counting exercise in this case as well. Fix a basis $B=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m\}$ for $GF(q^m)$ over $GF(q)$ such that the first  $m-1$ vectors span the kernel of the trace. A linear mapping $f$ preserves the kernel of the trace if and only if its matrix with respect to $B$ is of the form
$$
M_B(f)=\left(\begin{array}{ccccc}
f_{11}&f_{12}&\cdots&f_{1,m-1}&f_{1m}\\
f_{21}&f_{22}&\cdots&f_{2,m-1}&f_{2m}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots&\vdots\\
f_{m-1,1}&f_{m-1,2}&\cdots&f_{m-1,m-1}&f_{m-1,m}\\
0&0&\cdots&0&f_{m,m}
\end{array}\right)
$$
with $f_{m,m}\neq0$.
The mapping $f$ is bijective, iff (in addition to $f_{m,m}\neq0$) the upper left
$(m-1)\times (m-1)$ block is an invertible matrix.

It is clear that in all (except possibly some small degenerate cases) such matrices outnumber the scalar times a power of Frobenius mappings that you listed.

---

There is just so much wiggle room inside the kernel for your list to be anywhere near complete.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and thorough answer, I was quite off with my conjecture about these monomials. I will have to think how/if the question can be restated to suggest some other class of polynomials.

Comment: I have realized what my $f(x)$ should be. Indeed, I was asking too much. If you want, check my updated question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1183155/finite-field-question-involving-the-trace-and-a-permutation